# how to close dialog on (X) close button click event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, listbox, jquery-dialog

My mobile website has some multiselect controls. The multiselect that have a little number of items (5) appears normally, like a multiselect (in mobile style/format), but those that have more items than 5 appears like an dialog view, in a new page.
For some reason, the X button is unresponsive and doesn't have the colse effect. What should I do to make the X button works?
multiselect code:

```
<div class="field ">
        <label for="offices" class="select">
            Office(s):
        </label>
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Offices, Model.ListOfOffices, new { Multiple = "multiple", data_theme = "a", data_overlay_theme = "c", inline = "true", data_native_menu = "false" })
 </div>
```

jquery code:

```
$(".ui-icon-delete").click(function () {
  //$('.ui-dialog').hide(); no effect
  //$('div[data-role="dialog"]').popup("close"); no effect
  //$('div[data-role="dialog"]').dialog("close"); no effect
  //$('ui-dialog').dialog('close'); no effect
  $(this).parent().remove(); // this one close the dialog, but also remove the X button
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Great but what is the question?

Comment: How to close dialog on (X) button click event?

Answer (score 0):

Your dialog should have an ID associated with it. Considering your dialog has been initiated correctly you should be able to do:

```
<div id="dialog">
    <label for="offices" class="select">
        Office(s):
    </label>
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Offices, Model.ListOfOffices, new { Multiple = "multiple",  data_theme = "a", data_overlay_theme = "c", inline = "true", data_native_menu = "false" })
</div>
```

To close:

```
$(".ui-icon-delete").click(function () {
   $('#dialog').dialog('close');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me!:) I used your indication but on mobile it has no effect. On Desktop, it works ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[class=field]").css({ "display" : "none" });
```

Just Use `.css()` jQuery to hide that Element/Node by adding property of `display:none`.

### What It will do?

It will hide that element/node from current HTML tree but will not remove it.

Comment: Yes as you said, this just hide only the X button, I need to close the dialog. `$(this).parent().remove();` close the dialog(I need that), but also remove the X button (unwanted effect). Thanks for help!

Comment: @pisi If X button is child of that dialog box then there is no way that you hide dialog and show only the X button. As, parent node hides or removes. All its childs behave the same. And also can you tell me the attribute of that dialog box e.g. `className` or `ID` ?

Comment: the class of dialog is `ui-page ui-body-a ui-overlay-c ui-dialog ui-icon-delete ui-page-active`.

Comment: @pisi can you link me to your website? So, I can see what the problem really is. Adding comments will not going to help. Otherwise, we can't do anything.